# What is this voting system called?

Tags: voting-systems

Each person gets the same fixed number of points, and they can allocate the points to each candidate however they prefer, as long as the sum of points allocated equals the number of points given. The person with the most points wins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This system is called [cumulative voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_voting).

It is occasionally used on municipal level elections and also sees some use in workplace voting.

Ballots for this usually look like this, with one column for each vote:

[image: cumulative voting ballot]

This example ballot is from a district parliament election in the city of Hamburg, Germany.

Comment: the fractional ballot was what I was looking for. thanks

Comment: Note that ballots are usually valid if less than the maximum number of votes is cast. One does not have to spend them all.

Comment: "Muster" is German for "sample" by the way